# Hotkey to make toon run forward in WoW for OS X

Tags: world-of-warcraft, macos

On Windows I think the hotkey was <kbd>Insert</kbd> or something close to that to make my toon starting running forward, so that I did not have to hold a button down while my toon ran. So that I could switch apps and type this message while my toon is running for example.

So what is this hotkey on OS X? Or how can I get this done on OS X at least?

Comment: You should be able to set it to whatever you want in the keybinding settings.

Comment: As I recall, it's Num Lock in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default key for autorunning on OS X is <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

You can also change this to whatever you like by going in to the key binding menu (Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button, then press "Key bindings"), and changing the "Toggle autorun" key to what you wish.

Comment: fn + 6 did not work

Comment: Pretty sure the default key is still `Num Lock`/`Clear` in OS X. However, many mac key pads either have this key on `F6` doubled with a brightness control (hence, `FN`+`F6`), or, in some cases, lack it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the default is on a Mac, but I rebound my DELETE key to perform this function, since I don't use it for anything else and it's fairly easy to hit.

Answer (score 0):

in 3.3.5 my default shortcut was [Clear] key

Comment: Wasn't 3.3.5 the Ruby Sanctum? That's more than outdated by now. (We're at 7.0.x, 4 expansions ahead of WotLK)

Answer (score -1):

The default keybindings on a Mac are <kbd>/</kbd> (forward slash on numpad) or <kbd>'</kbd> (single quote).